# Is it possible to change the Google chrome default document area UI through Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In Google Chrome, when we open a new tab, we see icons of apps or the speed dial. I want to change the looks through an extension (if it is possible).

For example, instead of 6 app icons showing in a row, I would want to display 7 app icons in each row; and maybe I want to change the background color etc etc.

I'm asking this as recently I realize I can view the source through the developers tool (Inspect Element) and than change the layout and colors by changing the css there?

If not, is there a way I can change the installed files to give the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can override some of the pages that come in Chrome by default.

- Bookmark Manager
- History
- New Tab

Check the docs for more info:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/override.html

Comment: Prob with that tho is you have to totally replace the NTP, not just mod it.  Theres some NTP replacements out there as extensions you might want to look at if thats the course you want to take (havent looked at them in ages so cant comment on any).  But if all you want to do is mess with its css then you can use the userstylesheet.. http://brugbart.com/Articles/custom-style-sheets  ..it gets inserted into every single page (great for changing your scrollbars), so to just target the NTP I put `html[bookmarkbarattached]` at the start of the selector.

Comment: Sorry, its short for New Tab Page.